# Paged scrolling with dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm having a imageView which i would like to show some content upon. However i want the user to be able to scroll between different content upon the image. This content is an label where the label text is determined from an array? how can i create something like this where you also will be able to scroll backwards from for instance the first object to the last object in array?

**viewDidLoad**

```
    let firstFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height-100-64)

    var bigFrame : CGRect = firstFrame

    bigFrame.size.width *= 2.0

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: firstFrame)
    self.cameraView.addSubview(scrollView!)

    let firstView : UIView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
    firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    scrollView!.addSubview(firstView)
    let secondView : UIView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
    scrollView!.addSubview(secondView)
    scrollView!.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView!.contentSize = bigFrame.size

    scrollView?.hidden = true
```

**Further explanation**

So basically i for instance have a array like

```
var textArray = ["#COYS", "#SPURS", "#DELLEALLI"]
```

I then have a `UIImageView` in my view which i basically want to be able to scroll different texts from the array on top. However i also want it to be able so that you for instance can scroll backwords and it in this casw will go from `textArray[0]` to `textArray[2]`

[image]

Comment: can you maybe show some kind of sketch what your view should look like?

Comment: give me a couple of minutes i will do a sketch

Comment: I've tried to make a further explanation! Basically i just want to be able to scroll between different views on top of an image based on data from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option would be to use a pageviewcontroller. take a look at my example:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mezxx53rd3bvw7g/AAB6PuUIGZwccgxOsjLPfvcfa?dl=0

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was looking for